# how to send log from post-auth with Freeradius?

Tags: security, syslog, rsyslog, freeradius

I want to send message to remote syslog in post-auth section. Simple string with

```
"'%{User-Name}', '%{reply:Packet-Type}', '%{Calling-Station-Id}'"
```

How do it with FreeRADIUS 3 ?

Or..

How to split loggs by facility or priority?

Comment: checkout logstash/filebeat and grok to pickup the data you want from the logs... don't forget to rotate the files.

Comment: @JacobEvans i want send directly to remote machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using linelog

```
linelog log_postauth {
        filename = syslog
        syslog_facility = authpriv
        syslog_severity = info
        format = "ACCEPTED: %{User-Name} %{control:Tmp-String-0}, %{control:Tmp-String-1}, nas address: %{request:Called-Station-Id}, remote address: %{request:Calling-Station-Id}"
}

linelog log_postreject {
        filename = syslog
        syslog_facility = authpriv
        syslog_severity = warning
        format = "REJECTED: %{User-Name} %{control:Tmp-String-0}, %{control:Tmp-String-1}, nas address: %{request:Called-Station-Id}, remote address: %{request:Calling-Station-Id}"
}
```

And in server

```
post-auth {

    Post-Auth-Type ACCEPT {
        log_postauth
    }

    Post-Auth-Type REJECT {
        log_postreject
    }

}
```

Then sending it with rsyslog service

```
if  $syslogfacility-text == 'authpriv'
then {
    action(type="omfwd" target="10.254.144.141" protocol="udp" port="514")
}
```